# The benefit of libraries over object files

Tags: libraries

I have been reading topic regarding linux libraries
http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html

it mentions:

"The benefit is that each and every object file need not be stated when linking because the developer can reference the individual library"

I am not following this statement. I wonder if someone could have a further explanation or an example please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the best phrasing in the world, IIUC, and is a bit misleading. IMHO, instead of

> The benefit is that each and every object file need not be stated when linking because the developer can reference the *individual* library

it should say

> The benefit is that each and every object file need not be stated when linking because the developer can reference the *entire* library (as a named entity)

Basically, it means the following. In the absence of libraries, the author of what is now a library, could simply build a list of object files, like this:

```
a0.cpp -> a0.o
a1.cpp -> a1.o
...
```

and then she could write in the documentation "if you want functions x, y, and z", then you need to link with a3.o (because it contains x and z), a42.o (for y), but also a23.o, a15.o, and a72.o, because they contain necessary underlying parts.

This is of course unwieldy. A saner approach, as your link explains, is to create a single library from a state of common-purpose functions and classes. The instructions become "if you want the functionality of shooting up foo aliens, link with the foo_alien_shooting library".